# Bootstrap 4 highlight navbar Active

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How to highlight the current page on click ?

The nav-bar

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'page1' %}"> Football
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'page2' %}">Overview</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The script at the end of the .html

```
<script src="{% static "JS/master.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The .JS

```
$(".nav .nav-link").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

P.S I have never done JS before

Comment: @SO should make it compulsory to explain downvoting -,-

Comment: [That's been proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin). The consensus is "Nope".

Comment: Both of the answers given *could be* methods for determining your issue. When you're using different frameworks that rely on libraries in a project, there's a number of issues that might cause the behavior you're describing. We need more evidence to pinpoint the *exact* problem. (error message?) (conflicting libraries?) - what did you try to do to fix it?

Comment: Both answers are as concise as they can be at this point, based on your example.

Comment: So the content is loading, but the tab isn't highlighted? When you click on a tab, there's a request being sent to a server and data is returned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190884/discussion-between-wahwahwah-and-matthew).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason this happens is because when you click the link, you get redirected to a new page. So the styles set through JS reset. What I would do is set an id to each of your nav elements and then on page load add the active class, like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li id="link-football" class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'page1' %}"> Football
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li id="link-overview" class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'page2' %}">Overview</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then on page load you can do this:

```
//on the football page
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".active").removeClass("active");
   $("#link-football").addClass("active");
});
```

Further Explaining:

Any style you add through javascript gets reflected in the DOM, but it does not override the source file. So your static page always has `.active` set on the football page. When you load/reload the page either through F5, or a JS script, you also reload that static file with none of the changes done through JS being reflected. This is why I say to add the `active` class *after* the page loads, cause then you may know what page you're on, and therefore callout the active link.

I would also suggest not having anything set as active by default. You can do the homepage as default active, I see that happen, but it might cause yourself some confusion down the road if you forget to add the above script to a new page.

**Notes on using IDE and/or extending using `{% extends 'base.html' %}`**

To get it to work when extending the `**base.html**`, add the `{% block content %}`towards the ends of the page. i.e.

```
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

And on each subsequent **.html** page wrap the **JS** with **`<script> </script>`**

Comment: I'm not sure what html preprocessor/templating  you're using, but I gave you an example. The JS i provided should appear on both (or all) of your pages. But it will all differ slightly. `$("#link-football")` should only be used for the football page, PROVIDED that the element you want to be active has that as an id.

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell what's going on in `JS/master.js`, but you have the class `active` in both your `nav-item` and `nav-link`.

The first thing I'd try would be to remove the class `active` from `nav-link` and see if that works.

The next thing I'd try would be to add an "active" state to your CSS. I see Liquid tags in your `script src`, so if you're using a pre-made Jekyll theme it may already be adding the appropriate active state to the markup.

CSS

```
/* Active state */
.nav-item.active a {
  color: red;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can use jQuery which is used by Bootstrap. Your script is close, but it's looking for `.nav .nav-link`, which isn't in the HTML provided. It may be in the larger context of your markup, but you could target just `.nav-link` to make it work.

jQuery

```
var activeNavItem = $('.nav-item');

activeNavItem.click(function(){
  activeNavItem.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');  
});
```

That may or may not be helpful depending on your context. Here's a working demo on CodePen: https://codepen.io/mikejandreau/pen/BbXKZV

[image]

Comment: @Matthew - he's helping you troubleshoot. The reason you were downvoted (not by me - an *educated guess*) is that you didn't provide a testable model - just the outcome of a problem.