# dynamic active state of bootstrap 4 nav bar

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently:

1. I have 1 file called `header.php` which will contain `nav bar` that I will add to every page inside my so-called `dashboard` part of the website.
2. The `nav bar` contains 3 possible selections: `Tables -> tables.php`; `Workers -> workers.php`; `Admin Panel -> admin.php`
3. Each page is a simple `php` page with some HTML.

My `header.php` code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/src/main/home.php">CRM</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse font-weight-bold" id="navbarMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/src/main/tables.php" class="nav-link active">Tables</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Workers</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/src/main/admin.php" class="nav-link">Admin Panel</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, currently, my active 'Tab' is `Tables`. Let's say it will be loaded by default in dashboard so this makes sense.

However, how can mark `Tables` 'inactive' and mark `Workers` 'active' once `Workers` is selected?

I am aware of some way of achieving this using JS like in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402784/bootstrap-4-highlight-navbar-active) but unfortunately I wasn't able to figure how this works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a click event listener on each anchor, and then toggle the `active` class for each element. See this fiddle:

```js
$('#navbarMenu a').click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#navbarMenu a.active').removeClass('active');
  $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/src/main/home.php">CRM</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse font-weight-bold" id="navbarMenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/src/main/tables.php" class="nav-link active">Tables</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Workers</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/src/main/admin.php" class="nav-link">Admin Panel</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me yet another answer so fast :). This somewhat works though. I added `click listener` on every page (`tables.php`, `workers.php`, `admin.php`) and the nav bar started marking active whichever page was clicked, however, it stopped redirecting to the page it is supposed to. I thought perhaps that extra script you added before the `nav` would change the behavior, but when I added it, nothing changed. If I remove the `click listener` and the `script` in `header` everything works as it used to.